# How to publish PDB files along with Excel add-in ClickOnce installation?

Tags: excel, vsto, clickonce, pdb-files

I need to publish PDB files along with DLLs of my Excel add-in. ClickOnce allows to select custom application files, but for Excel add-in this button is not available.
Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsto/thread/3f0b47fa-bd36-4033-a0d4-6875122ab010

Comment: @Kiru, why don't you make this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check similar problem discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsto/thread/3f0b47fa-bd36-4033-a0d4-6875122ab010)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in for my Outlook AddIn this way:

- create a post build event: `copy "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb" "$(ProjectDir)"`. This creates a copy of the pdb to the root folder of the project.
- Add this copy of the pdb as a link to your project.

When you publish your project now, the pdb will also be deployed. Skipping part 1 and directly linking the pdb in the debug\bin folder will not work.